# A Poetic Ladder

Tags: riddle, poetry

```
Help me, for I have become longer -- taller -- thinner
I am more ungenerous, more unwilling to give
Sharply, I will hurt you, wound you
A musician of the purest variety
I burn, slightly and superficially
A functional, right ratio
Here now abbreviated
Included within
Me
```

---

**What is this poem talking about?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each line

> is given by the answer to the previous line, minus one letter.

---

Help me, for I have become longer -- taller -- thinner

> This piece of spaghetti is **stringier** than that one!

I am more ungenerous, more unwilling to give

> A miserly, parsimonious person is **stingier** than a charitable person.

Sharply, I will hurt you, wound you

> The **stinger** of a wasp for example causes a small wound.

A musician of the purest variety

> A **singer** might be considered pure as they only use their voice, no other "impurities" like instruments.

I burn, slightly and superficially

> I thought I had ruined the food, but I had only **singe**d it.

A functional, right ratio

> The mathematical ratio of a right angled triangle of the opposite and the hypotenuse is the **sine**.

Here now abbreviated

> But who writes "sine"? **sin**(θ) = o/h;

Included within

> The answer is actually with**in** the line

Me

> **I** figured this one out first and worked backwards.

Comment: For the three-letter one, it's "sin" because that's the abbreviation for the sine function.

Comment: Ah of course! I was looking for an abbreviation of "here" or "now"

Comment: And the number of words in each clue is the same as the number of letters in each word.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is:

> A tensile failure test

Help me, for I have become longer -- taller -- thinner

> A tensile specimen fails by lengthening and becoming thinner

I am more ungenerous, more unwilling to give

> It becomes harder (work hardens), which could be described as ungenerous (translating from the scientific term to the usual english usage), and gives with more difficulty (modulus increases).

Sharply, I will hurt you, wound you

> Look, I don't really think this is the answer, so this gets more and more *scretched* (excuse the pun).  Sharply could refer to a sharpie impact test, or the fact that a sharp edge makes a stress concentrator, which tend to be the break point, or the possible sharp edges left over after it snaps

A musician of the purest variety

> Mmm.  Well, I guess we could be performing the test on a musical string.

I burn, slightly and superficially

> Often there is localized heating at the break point

A functional, right ratio

> The ratio between the length and the cross sectional area (okay, okay, I know it's weak - I didn't see your answer written here!)

Here now abbreviated

> Break = abbreviated

Included within
Me

> Inclusions can be the source of the weakness.  *Sigh*  It's just so *weak*.  I feel *broken*.  Torn into two.  Rent asunder.  Unable to hold it all together.  Brittle.  Someone give this dog a *dog bone*.

Comment: Apparently, SE couldn't tell I was even human from that answer!!

Comment: Computers don't appreciate puns.

Comment: It seems people don't either.  sad face.